# Get Facebook posts on my application

Tags: c#, vb.net, facebook, facebook-apps

Is there any way we can get posts, status of Facebook to show in our application based on some Keywords or GEO location. I have done it for Twitter using developer account where I used to apply some token keys and gets the result in json format. 
Is there any similar way to get posts from Facebook developer account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Search API to search based on keywords. Like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=football&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

To search for objects near a geographical location, use type=location and add the center and distance parameters: /search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

Here's more detail: http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/facebook/api/facebook-graph-api/docs/reference/search